# how to achieve distinct records based on the priority

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table with data like below,

```
id  code    data1   data2   country
1   1      A           NULL      IND
1   1      B            B        NZ
1   1                            CA
1   1      C           Z         WI
1   1      D           S         UK
2   2      NULL        NULL       IND
2   2       S          NULL       NZ
2   2       NULL        K         CA
2   2       T           T          WI
2   2       R           K          UK
3   3       NULL        A          WI
3   3       NULL        a          UK
```

the record will be populates based on the priority on country field. the priority is IND,NZ,CA,WI,UK

if there is any NULL,blank in data1,data2 fields data will populates from the next priority record.

So, My expected result is :
target table:

```
id  code    data1   data2   country
1   1          A       B    IND
2   2          S       K    IND
3   3          NULL    A    WI
```

Can any one help me with the query to achive the above result set.

I have added few more rows for better understanding on the query.

---

Comment: And if next priority record is also NULL,blank ?

Comment: And are you sure all id = 1?

Comment: it should got to next priority record, if all priority records have null/blank it should populate null/blank only

Comment: id is identical to code?

Comment: I have added few more rows for your understanding in the above table.

Comment: Yes, it is identical

Comment: second field is not allowing in order by Clause for first_value() function in Hive. Can any one give me alternative way to achieve the above out put.

Comment: What is the type of the 2nd field?

Comment: its numeric only.  
I am getting the error 'FAILED: SemanticException Range based Window Frame can have only 1 Sort Key' when I added second field (Priority) in order by clause. I have executed the same SQL @Gurv provided.

Comment: Add to the `over` clause `rows between unbounded preceding and current row`

Comment: first_value(data1) over (partition by id 
            order by case when data1 is null or data1 = '' then 1 else 0 end rows between unbounded preceding and current row) data1 , Like this?

Comment: Yes..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use case to get priorities and use first_value on it.

```
select id, max(code), max(data1), max(data2), max(country)
from (
    select
        id,
        code,
        first_value(data1) over (partition by id 
            order by case when data1 is null or data1 = '' then 1 else 0 end * 10 + priority) data1,
        first_value(data2) over (partition by id 
            order by case when data2 is null or data2 = '' then 1 else 0 end * 10 + priority) data2,
        first_value(country) over (partition by id 
            order by case when country is null or country = '' then 1 else 0 end * 10 + priority) country
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            case country
                when 'IND' then 1
                when 'NZ' then 2
                when 'CA' then 3
                when 'WI' then 4
                when 'UK' then 5
            end priority
        from your_table t
    ) t
) t group by id;
```

Produces:

```
ID  MAX(CODE)   MAX(DATA1)  MAX(DATA2)  MAX(COUNTRY)
1   1           A           B           IND
2   2           S           K           IND
3   3           NULL        A           WI
```

#### EDIT:

You can alternatively use `FIELD` function (available in hive, MySQL) to produce the priorities as suggested by @Dudu in the comments below:

```
field(country,'IND','NZ','CA','WI','UK')
```

See:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: Same here.  If data1 of IND is null you'll get the wrong country

Comment: I doubt that country can be null, but it will do the job

Comment: Same here - does not cover the blank use-case

Comment: Thanks GurV, why we are using first_value() function on country field as we already defined the priority in case statement, so, we can get the distinct records based on row_number () over(partition by ID,code order by priority) as rnk, then we can filtered with all result set where rnk=1.

Comment: @ssk - Thing is that we need a value of one column based on order of another column. First_value function is perfect for this.

Comment: Thanks GurV, why we are using first_value() function on country field as we already defined the priority in case statement, so, we can get the distinct records based on row_number () over(partition by ID,code order by priority) as rnk, then we can filtered with all result set where rnk=1

Comment: @ssk - Yes, that's one more way to do it.

Comment: Thanks GurV, how to achieve the same logic in SQL server or any other dbs

Comment: @ssk - It should work in ANSI complaint databases such as SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres as such.

Comment: The solution might be database specific. Database that supports `IGNORE NULL` for analytic functions enable a cleaner solution.

Comment: @GurV - I have added few more rows for ID -3. So, is still your SQL works for the edited output? Can you please confirm

Comment: @ssk - Yes. Just tested. It works correctly and produces your expected output.

Comment: @GurV - Thanks for the confirmation and help ! is first_value() functions will work on all versions of hive

Comment: @GurV - second field is not allowing in order by Clause for first_value() function in Hive. Can you please give me any alternative way to achieve the above out put.

Comment: Are we get the same out put if I omitted PRIORITY in order by clause

Comment: @ssk - No the output will not be the same. Why is not allowed? Do you get an error? If so, what exactly does the error message say?

Comment: @GurV -I am getting the error 'FAILED: SemanticException Range based Window Frame can have only 1 Sort Key' when I added second field (Priority) in order by clause

Comment: @ssk - Update my answer to use single sort key

Comment: @GurV - first_value(data1) over (partition by id 
            order by case when data1 is null or data1 = '' then 1 else 0 end * 10 + priority) , *10+Priority what it does?

Comment: @ssk - it's a trick to convert two key sort to one key. say value of a, b are 1, 1 and  0, 2.... then result will be 11 and 2 which is will be if sorted as order by a, b will result in (0, 2), (1, 1). If you do order by a * 10 + b provided that you know a is going to be between 0 and 9, will produce the same result.

Comment: @Gurv - Got it,Thanks for the alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hive has the `first_value()` function, which can be used for this purpose:

```
select distinct id, code,
       first_value(data1) over (partition by id, code
                                order by (case when data1 is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                                         (case country when 'IND' then 1 when 'NZ' then 2 when 'CA' then 3 when 'WI' then 4 when 'UK' then 5 else 6 end)
                               ) as data1,
       first_value(data2) over (partition by id, code
                                order by (case when data2 is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                                         (case country when 'IND' then 1 when 'NZ' then 2 when 'CA' then 3 when 'WI' then 4 when 'UK' then 5 else 6 end)
                               ) as data2,
       first_value(country) over (partition by id, code
                                order by (case when data1 is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                                         (case country when 'IND' then 1 when 'NZ' then 2 when 'CA' then 3 when 'WI' then 4 when 'UK' then 5 else 6 end)
                               ) as country
from t;
```

I am not a big fan of `select distinct` with window functions.  In this case, it seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: No. If data1 of IND is null you'll get the wrong country

Comment: Also does not cover the blank use-case

Comment: Thanks @Dudu, instead of distinct we can use row_number () over(partition by ID,code order by priority) as rnk, then we can filtered with all result set where rnk=1.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Gordon Linoff- second field is not allowing in order by Clause for first_value() function in Hive. Can you please give me any alternative way to achieve the above out put.

Comment: I am getting the error  'FAILED: SemanticException Range based Window Frame can have only 1 Sort Key' when I added second field (Priority) in order by clause

Answer (score 0):

Another approach based on MIN of STRUCT.

For the order I'm using the function `field` ( `field(country,'IND','NZ','CA','WI','UK')`).
Since it was missing, I have added it to the documentation.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

```
select      id
           ,min (code)                                                                                                           as code
           ,min (case when coalesce(trim(data1),'') <> '' then struct(field(country,'IND','NZ','CA','WI','UK'),data1) end).col2  as data1
           ,min (case when coalesce(trim(data2),'') <> '' then struct(field(country,'IND','NZ','CA','WI','UK'),data2) end).col2  as data2
           ,min (struct(field(country,'IND','NZ','CA','WI','UK'),country)).col2                                                  as country

from        mytable

group by    id

order by    id
;
```

#### Demo

```
create table mytable 
(
    id      int
   ,code    int
   ,data1   string
   ,data2   string
   ,country string
);

insert into mytable values

    (1 ,1 ,'A'  ,NULL ,'IND')
   ,(1 ,1 ,'B'  ,'B'  ,'NZ' )
   ,(1 ,1 ,''   ,''   ,'CA' )
   ,(1 ,1 ,'C'  ,'Z'  ,'WI' )
   ,(1 ,1 ,'D'  ,'S'  ,'UK' )
   ,(2 ,2 ,NULL ,NULL ,'IND')
   ,(2 ,2 ,'S'  ,NULL ,'NZ' )
   ,(2 ,2 ,NULL ,'K'  ,'CA' )
   ,(2 ,2 ,'T'  ,'T'  ,'WI' )
   ,(2 ,2 ,'R'  ,'K'  ,'UK' )
   ,(3 ,3 ,NULL ,'A'  ,'WI' )
   ,(3 ,3 ,NULL ,'a'  ,'UK' )
;
```

---

```
select      id
           ,min (code)                                                                                                           as code
           ,min (case when coalesce(trim(data1),'') <> '' then struct(field(country,'IND','NZ','CA','WI','UK'),data1) end).col2  as data1
           ,min (case when coalesce(trim(data2),'') <> '' then struct(field(country,'IND','NZ','CA','WI','UK'),data2) end).col2  as data2
           ,min (struct(field(country,'IND','NZ','CA','WI','UK'),country)).col2                                                  as country

from        mytable

group by    id

order by    id
;
```

---

```
+----+------+-------+-------+---------+
| id | code | data1 | data2 | country |
+----+------+-------+-------+---------+
|  1 |    1 | A     | B     | IND     |
|  2 |    2 | S     | K     | IND     |
|  3 |    3 | NULL  | A     | WI      |
+----+------+-------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution @Dude

Comment: What .col2 does @Dude

Comment: .col2 is the 2nd column of a struct